# image_url not working: NoMethodError in .. undefined method `image_url' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to generate a url (not an actual image, just the url to an image) in the controller, using `image_path('my_image.png')` (it's for a `<meta>` tag, so it needs the raw url).

But when I start the server and visit the page:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#index
undefined method `image_path' for #<UsersController:0x00007fef850c6468>
```

And it's the same if I use `image_url('myimage.png')` as well:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#index
undefined method `image_url' for #<UsersController:0x00007fea106cfaa0>
```

And I've tried both

```
image_path('assets/myimage.png')
```

and

```
image_url('assets/myimage.png')
```

but same outcome.

I've even tried including `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` inside the controller, but still `NoMethodError in UsersController` etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Including `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` should be ok, how did you include the line 
of code?

Comment: @eux I literally had `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper` in the controller (since that's what worked in the rails console), but it needed to be `include ActionView::Helpers:: AssetUrlHelper` (or `include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`, they both seem to work). But I was missing `include`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I'm trying to use a view helper inside the controller, so I needed to include it in the controller:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
```

Then `image_url('my_image.png')` produced the url as expected